# Jasmine - How to test element id changes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, jasmine

Let's say I have a button with the certain id `submit_button`, and now I change its id in an if-else block, like:

```
$(document).on('click', '#submit_button', App.books.submitForm);
if(event.target.id == 'from_table'){
  $('#submit_button').attr('id','submit_button_2');
  // do something except call submitForm()...
}else {
  $('#submit_button_2').attr('id','submit_button');
  // do something and it will call submitForm() when clicked
}
```

My question is how can I test this case? For example, sometimes the button's id will not be changed to `submit_button_2` when the target.id is not `from_table`, then line 6 is useless in this case since `submit_button_2` doesn't exist.

I know I need to test if the `submit_button_2` has changed to `submit_button`, but do I need to write a test case for "if there's no `submit_button_2` then the id wouldn't be changed"? If yes, how to write this test case?

Please let me know if I need to add more things. Thank you!

Comment: Aside from the issue, changing `id` attributes at runtime is a code smell, and not something you should really be doing.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I'm sorry Rory, I do not quite understand your saying. Could you give me some hints when you have a chance?